# Decrypting SSL session using pre-master for any PCAP/WinCAP

Tags: man-in-the-middle, decryption

i am trying to Decrypt SSL session using pre-master key for any PCAP/WinCAP HTTP plain-text. is there any idea how i can use/decrypt my pre-master key to decrypt SSL session. i am using pcap analyser.

Comment: You are using what tool? This one: http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~tpc/PCAP/? And you are asking us how to use it?

Comment: Without knowing what the tool is, there is not much we can do. If the tool is non-standard, then you have to find and read the manual. I'm not sure why you are not using a standard tool, like Wireshark that has abundant documentation and tutorials.

Comment: @schroeder  . i  have already developed own libpcap packet sniffer on Linux environment which works as same as what Wireshark does. now want to add facility of decryption function using pre-master log file.

i have read ref. RFC 5246 and got the idea. i would like know does Wireshark's decryption system source code is available on web? if anything similar is available or present i would like to see it to develop my own. if you know or could help me in this section. i am facing problems on how should i start programming in decryption.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean, like this: https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark ? No where in your question do you state that you want to *code* your own way to do this. This is a programming question and there are multiple other projects that are open source that show you how to approach the problem.